# disable element in jquery

Tags: jquery, css, class

My [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6oo73Lay/) is here.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.abc').click(function () {
        $('#test').after('<textarea cols="125" rows="2" id="pReply" style="background-color:red;"></textarea>')
    });
});
```

When I click on 'ABC' text, it will append a textarea. After appending I want to disable the text 'ABC'. That means, It should not append text boxes more than one.

Comment: Remember, when using JSFiddle, you *must* include the code of your fiddle (as @Jeff B was kind enough to edit for you), as the error message told you before submitting this question.

Comment: Thanks. I got the error message, but could not understand it.

Comment: No problem. Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Bind the event using `.one()`. Once the event runs the first time, jQuery will automatically unbind it from the element for you.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.abc').one('click', function () {
        $('#test').after('<textarea cols="125" rows="2" id="pReply" style="background-color:red;"></textarea>')
    });
});
```

**Reference:** [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/6oo73Lay/2/)

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the unbind function where you would unbind the click event after the call gets executed

JS code

```
$('.abc').click( function()
     {
         $('#test').after('<textarea cols="125" rows="2" id="pReply" style="background-color:red;"></textarea>' );
         $(this).unbind('click');                
      }
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6oo73Lay/6/)

More on [unbind](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) function

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use this type of function

```
<script>
        var isClicked = false;
        function appendIt(){
               if(!isClicked){
                       //append text area
               }
               isClicked = true;
        }
</script>

<h1 onclick="appendIt()"> chabadabada </h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

U can bind using `one` or using the `$(this).off(event)` after triggering the event.
like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.abc').click( function(event){
        $('#test').after('<textarea cols="125" rows="2" id="pReply" style="background-color:red;"></textarea>' );
        $( this ).off( event );
    });
});
```

or:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.abc').one('click',function(){
        $('#test').after('<textarea cols="125" rows="2" id="pReply" style="background-color:red;"></textarea>' );
    });
});
```

Hope it useful!

Answer (score -3):

Just remove the click function with jquery